# Display going to sleep and not turning on

Tags: hdmi, display, raspberry-pi-os

I am working on a kiosk powered by RaspberryPi 4, and I have a problem when the pi is running with a DVI/VGA adapter.

The issue is that monitor is that the monitor goes to sleep during the night: I manually set blanking mode using  `DISPLAY=:0 xset +dpms && DISPLAY=:0 xset s blank`, and at the time of "wake up", I set it on using `DISPLAY=:0  xset -dpms && DISPLAY=:0 xset s noblank`.

Everything works fine with HDMI displays, but suddenly it stopped working with the display attached with a Micro HDMI/DVI adapter.
Even manually forcing display on using `xset s reset && xset dpms force on` does not works.

If I check the status with `xset` I got:

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

And the display is correctly powered up, checked using `vcgencmd display_power`.
The screen remains in sleep state and won't turn on.